# Can't acess some folder on my own pc

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I can't access some of the folders in my PC. 
I have Windows 10 and I want to open windows app folder and its saying

> You don't currently have permission to access this folder

What should i do to gain acess on floders

Comment: By `windows app folder` do you mean `C:\Windows` ?

Comment: Take ownership... Google for "taking ownership of folder"

Comment: @Vylix if you have windows 10 open any app like twitter,fb,instagram Then go to task manager and then open file location of these apps.that  folder I can't acess it

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why do you *want* to access those folders?

Comment: @Run5k actually i just want to see some content inside it

Answer (score 0):

There are various Windows files and folders that are intentionally hidden, unalterable or inaccessible, or all three. This is for good reason, to protect system files.

[image: Special Windows folders]

For example, in the image above,

- **AppData** contains user data for Windows and for some applications, such as the Firefox user profile. This folder is marked *Hidden*, but can be seen if you choose to view *Hidden* and *System* files, and the data can be accesses and can be changed, without taking ownership. In most cases, changes here will cause no, or limited damage if an error is made.
- **Application Data** is a [hidden link, containing no data, and is only for backwards compatibility.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414241/application-data-folder-in-windows-7) Any change to this link would cause some programs to fail.
- **Windows.old** and its subfolders are accessible, but the user is denied permission to make any change -- for good reason. This contains *System* files for Windows, from the Windows folder before the last major update. Since the update process is somewhat generic, specific files that may be peculiar to your PC (e.g. audio drivers) are backed up here, and restored if there is some issue. 30 days after an update, Windows allows these files to be deleted through *Cleanup*. From my own sad experience, I can say that trying to delete some of these folders can badly mung Windows to the extent that restoring the entire partition from an image was the best fix.

Another issue with taking ownership of a file or folder is that it may cause Windows *Update* to fail. *Update* expects certain folders with specific attributes and owner, and can be a *real* pain to fix if changes are made. Again, I speak from experience... It only took a few days to fix the mess I had made.

There are also NTFS files used to maintain the directory structure that cannot be seen at all in *Explorer*, but can be viewed from another OS (e.g. Linux).

In short, *do not take ownership of a folder and do not change its attributes* unless you have a specific reason to do so, have made a backup image of your HDD, and have time and knowledge to restore the disk.

Answer (score 0):

The folder you are looking for is possibly for programs or Windows. So I suggest you do not edit this folder. But there is how to access that:
1. Right-click on the folder.
2. Click Properties.
3. Go to Security tab.
4. Click Advanced.
5. Click "Change" in front of "Owner: xxx".
6. Click Advanced, then Find. A list of Users appear. Double Click your user name.
7.Chek the check box "Replace owner on subcontainers and objects" in the "Advanced Security Settings".
8. Apply the setting, click OK and Click "Advanced" again.
9. Click Add In the bottom.
10. Click "Select a principal" and select your account as in level 6.
11. Check  the Checkbox "Full Control".
12. Done!, OK>OK>OK and you can access the folder.